# Language choice for GameBoy Advance Homebrew Development

Tags: c, assembly, homebrew, game-boy-advance

I was reading a ton of tutorials and wanted to get into GBA Homebrew

Now, should i use C or assembly? I already know a bit of C, but asm wouldnt be difficult to me, and i was interested in learning it anyways.

So, which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C is **easier** to develope, specially complex and long programs, and it will take you **way less time** than making it in assembly, plus you can write assembly in c. Assembly on the other hand can get you **better performance** if done correctly and it's more **flexible**.

So I would say go ahead with C

Comment: Actually, you would be hard stretched to find an assembly programmer who could write code that out performs a C compiler with all the optimizations available nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule for the asm vs C no matter what platform (that has both choices) is to use C and only if you really have to use asm for performance or other reasons use asm...